# Erro ao retornar objetos salvo no banco entre activites - Objeto nulo

Tags: java, android, banco-de-dados, sqlite

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação simples de preencher um formulário, exibir os cadastrados e poder editá-los. Estou usando o relacionamento um para muitos, onde um paciente pode conter várias fotos, fotos essas que estão sendo salvar através de seus endereços de caminho numa lista de string. 
Depois de salvo no banco, listado os cadastrados, ao escolher um paciente para editá-lo está o seguinte erro:

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.List br.ufrn.project.model.Foto.getImagem()' on a null object reference
```

Não esta passando o objeto paciente de uma intente para outra, mesmo serializando a classe. 
Aqui está a classe Paciente:

```
public class Paciente implements Serializable {
@Expose
private int id;
@Expose
private String nome;
@Expose
private String cpf;
@Expose
public  Foto foto;
@Expose
private String data;
getter e setter...

public class Foto  implements Serializable {

@Expose
private List<String> imagem;
@Expose
private int id;
@Expose
private String status;

public List<String> getImagem() {
return imagem;
}

getter e setter...
```

Na intent de listar eu busco os pacientes do banco e adiciono em uma lista:

```
List<Paciente> list = pacienteDAO.buscar();//Retorna uma lista de pacientes salvo no banco
```

Dentro do adapter estou passando o objeto paciente da tela de listar para a tela de edição.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ListarActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
Paciente p = pacientes.get(i);
intent.putExtra("nome", pacientes.get(i).getNome());
intent.putExtra("cpf", pacientes.get(i).getCpf());
intent.putExtra("data", pacientes.get(i).getData());
intent.putExtra("id", pacientes.get(i).getId());
intent.getExtras().putSerializable("image", (Serializable) pacientes.get(i).getFoto().getImagem());
                        //intent.getExtras().putSerializable("status", pacientes.get(i).getFoto().getStatus());
                        startActivity(intent);
```

Na intent de ediçao eu resgato o bundle com o objeto passado, onde eu coloco todas os caminhos das imagens numa Lista de string:

```
List<String> photos = new ArrayList<>();
photos = (List<String>) bundle.getSerializable("image");
//status = (Foto) bundle.getSerializable("status");
pac.setId(bundle.getInt("id"));
pac.setNome(bundle.getString("nome"));
pac.setCpf(bundle.getString("cpf"));
pac.setData(bundle.getString("data"));
pac.setFoto(pac.getFoto());
pac.setFoto(status);
nome.setText(pac.getNome());
cpf.setText(pac.getCpf());
mDisplayDate.setText(pac.getData());
countImage.setText(photos.size()+" selecionado(s)");

btAlterar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
btSalvar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Por algum motivo ele não está trazendo o fotos corretamente, retornando Null. 
Método salvar da activity principal:

```
public void salvarPaciente(){
    Foto ft = new Foto();
    pacienteDao = new PacienteDAO(this);
    pac.setNome(nome.getText().toString());
    pac.setCpf(cpf.getText().toString());
    pac.setData(date);
    ft.setStatus("Enviar");
    ft.setImagem(caminhoDaImagem);
    pac.setFoto(ft);
    pacienteDao.inserirPaciente(pac);

    pacienteDao.inserirFoto(ft);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Paciente salvo com sucesso!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ListarActivity.class);
    startActivity(myIntent);
}
```

No lado do banco:

```
public long inserirFoto(Foto ft){

    List<String> fotos = ft.getImagem();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    for(int i = 0; i < fotos.size(); i++) {

        values.put("status","Enviado" );
        values.put("imagem", fotos.get(i));
        Log.d("TAG", fotos.get(i));
    }return banco.insert("imagens", null, values);
}

public long inserirPaciente(Paciente paciente){

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("nome", paciente.getNome());
    values.put("cpf", paciente.getCpf());
    values.put("data", paciente.getData());
    return banco.insert("paciente", null, values);
}
```

Comment: Amigo, se você tentar enviar o paciente sem as imagens, esta indo? Por exemplo, se você comentar `intent.getExtras().putSerializable("image", (Serializable) pacientes.get(i).getFoto().getImagem());` e enviar, os dados do paciente (sem os dados das fotos) chegam na outra view?

Comment: envia sim, so quando coloco as imagens que dá erro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom, no android você pode passar dados utilizando o `parceable` ou o `serializable`. Com o `serializable` acredito que o jeito mais simples de fazer isso é enviar o objeto inteiro, já que você esta enviando todos os atributos do método separadamente, se substituir pelo próprio objeto ficaria muito mais simples, veja abaixo.

Na view onde você envia os dados, troque para enviar o objeto inteiro:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
Paciente p = pacientes.get(i);
intent.putExtra("paciente", p);
startActivity(intent);
```

E na view de edição, para resgatar faça assim:

```
Intent i = getIntent();
Paciente paciente = (Paciente)i.getSerializableExtra("paciente");
```

Com o objeto inteiro agora você pode utilizar os métodos get do mesmo para pegar os valores dos atributos.

Comment: aparece a seguinte mensagem: getextras() in intent cannot be applied ao mudar o codigo da tela que envia os dados.

Comment: @TecnologiadaNet perdão, erro meu, na view que envia deve utilizar `putExtra`.

Comment: @TecnologiadaNet conseguiu enviar após a correção que mencionei?

Comment: Murilo, desculpa a demora. Precisei viajar de ultima hora e so hj pude pegar no codigo. Murilo, acredito que o problema esta no SQL do salvar as imagens. Estou recuperando todos os demais dados conforme me indicou na resposta, somente as imagens retorna null.